# Cannot background HTTPie http request with `&` in .sh script

Tags: bash, httpie, backgrounding

How come this works from the BASH prompt:

```
/testproj> http http://localhost:5000/ping/ &
[1] 10733
(env)
/testproj> HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 17 Nov 2018 19:27:01 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.6.4

{}
```

... but fails when executed from in a `.sh`:

```
/testproj> cat x.sh
http http://localhost:5000/ping/ &
(env)
/testproj> ./x.sh
(env)
/testproj> HTTP/1.0 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 178
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sat, 17 Nov 2018 19:29:00 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.6.4
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>



<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

?

EDIT: `http` is HTTPie

EDIT: `type http` gives `http is hashed (/testproj/env/bin/http)`

EDIT: One can reproduce the error with just `http http://www.google.com </dev/null &` (Thanks @e36freak)

EDIT: from e36freak on IRC:

> it appears to be an issue with `stdin`
>   i get the same error with just `http http://www.google.com </dev/null`
>   `http` wants `stdin` to be attached to a `tty` it looks like
>   for whatever reason
>   couldn't find it in the man page but i'm sure it's out there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most like like need to include the `--ignore-stdin` option to prevent httpie from trying to read it. See: https://httpie.org/doc#scripting